# Converting byte array to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, byte

Is there an easy way to convert a byte array to a string so the following unit test passes?  I can't find an encoding that works for all values.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestBytToString()
  {
     byte[] bytArray = new byte[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < bytArray.Length; i++)
     {
        bytArray[i] = (byte)i;
     }
     string x = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytArray);
     for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
     {
        int y = (int)x[i];
        Assert.AreEqual(i, y);
     }
  }
```

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll` should work for creating a `char[]`, which you can pass to a string constructor.

Comment: Avoiding the "why would you do this?" question, the only encoding this operation would be valid in would be ASCII, I think.

Comment: Ascii fails Expected: <128>, Actual: <63>

Comment: When I got your code and tested with the following , test passes 
`string x = new string(bytArray.Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray());`

Credit goes to [@Ricky](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573587/1991801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestBytToString()
  {
     byte[] bytArray = new byte[256];
     ushort[] usArray = new ushort[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < bytArray.Length; i++)
     {
        bytArray[i] = (byte)i;

     }

     string x = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytArray);
     for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
     {
        int y = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(x.Substring(i, 1))[0];
        Assert.AreEqual(i, y);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` should do a trick for you.

Comment: What if it's not in UTF8?

Comment: So what encoding is it? If it's a ASCII, it still in the margins of UTF8, which is famous for shrinking to the necessary size.

Comment: When I use UTF8 it fails with Expected: <128>, Actual: <65533>.

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytArray, 0, bytArray.Length);
```

Comment: When I use the above it fails with Expected: <128>, Actual: <65533>.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytArray);
```

Comment: When I use the above it fails whe Expected: <128>, Actual: <8364>

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know everthing above value 127 in byte is considered a negative number and as char can only take positive values it results with an unknown char in every encoding you take.

You might want to convert the byte array to unsigned short (ushort) and then to string...