# string to byte[] without encoding or changing actual bytes at string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, arrays

assume i got the following `byte[]`

```
0C 00 21 08 01 00 00 00 86 1B 06 00 54 51 53 65 72 76 65 72
```

with `bitconverter BitConverter.ToString` i can convert it to

```
0C-00-21-08-01-00-00-00-86-1B-06-00-54-51-53-65-72-76-65-72
```

how do i convert it back from string to `byte[]` to get

```
0C 00 21 08 01 00 00 00 86 1B 06 00 54 51 53 65 72 76 65 72
```

ascii encoding and other methods always getting me the equivalent bytes to the string but what i really need is the string to be byte[] as it is, i know if i did a reversing operation (using getbytes then tostring) ill end up with the same string but what i care about is while at getbytes to get the exact bytes

as i said

to put

```
0C-00-21-08-01-00-00-00-86-1B-06-00-54-51-53-65-72-76-65-72
```

AS `string`

and get

```
0C 00 21 08 01 00 00 00 86 1B 06 00 54 51 53 65 72 76 65 72
```

As `byte[]`

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this

```
byte[] bytes = str.Split('-').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: that works, thanks buddy, no wondering why i didn't figure it out on my own :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SoapHexBinary` class  in `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001` namespace

```
string s = "0C-00-21-08-01-00-00-00-86-1B-06-00-54-51-53-65-72-76-65-72";
byte[] buf  = SoapHexBinary.Parse(s.Replace("-"," ")).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remenber that BitConverter.ToString returns an equivalent hexadecimal string representation,so
if you decide to stick with it converting back as follow:

```
string temp = BitConverter.ToString(buf);//buf is your array.
byte[] newbuf = temp.Split('-').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s,16)).ToArray();
```

But the safest way to convert bytes to string and back is base64:

```
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
byte[] result = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134671/c-how-can-i-safely-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-string-and-back

Comment: It is about `not to get "invalid" unicode sequences (encoding.GetString(byteArray) for ex.,)`. What can be the problem when you only use the chars `0-9` and `A-F` ?